# How can I refer the ManagedType<X> of an Entity type X?

Tags: jpa, metamodel

I created a utility method look like this.

```
public static <T extends BaseEntity> Optional<T> findByUri(
        final EntityManager entityManager,
        final Class<T> entityClass,
        final ManagedType<? super T> entityType,
        final Supplier<String> uriSupplier) {
    return findByUniqueAttribute(
            entityManager,
            entityClass,
            () -> entityType.getSingularAttribute(
                    PersistenceConstants.URI_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, String.class),
            uriSupplier);
}
```

Not with given entity class `MyEntity.class`, how can I refer `MyEntity_.class` for `ManagedEntity<MyEntity>`?

Should I just find the class postfixed with `_`?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out but I'm not sure.

```
final EntityType<MyEntity> entityType =
    entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(MyEntity.class)
```

I can change my utility class like this.

```
public static <T extends BaseEntity> Optional<T> findByUri(
        final EntityManager entityManager,
        final Class<T> entityClass,
        final Supplier<String> uriSupplier) {
    return findByUniqueAttribute(
            entityManager,
            entityClass,
            () -> entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(entityClass)
            .getSingularAttribute(
                    PersistenceConstants.URI_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, String.class),
            uriSupplier);
}
```